# Localizable.strings working but not working for italian else storyboard localised perfectly

Tags: ios, localization

I have localized my project in 5 languages english, Chinese(Simplified), French, Spanish, Italian. All are working perfect, storyboard are converted perfectly in all five languages but Localizable.strings file not picking up italian language else storyboard converted to Italian. I think `NSLocalizedString` not working for Italian but why?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue after long time in Localizable.strings file in spanish in one string there is like this

```
"Please enter valid email id" = "Inserisci l'ID di posta valida";
```

the problem is due to Spanish conversed string contain `"'"` in the string in second word `"l'ID"` so Spanish strings are not picking up. after removing ' from Spanish conversed string my Localization working properly. But I still don't get it properly why this is happening.